# Terminate loop in Thread on Member Change within Class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class that runs a loop on a seperate thread and I want it to break when I change the value of a member to false:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>

class A
{
public:
    void ChangeLoop(){
        loop = !loop;
            if(loop){
                std::future<void> fi = std::async(std::launch::async, &A::RunLoop, this, std::ref(loop));
            }
    }
    void RunLoop(std::atomic<bool> &loop_ref){

        while(loop_ref){
            emit(loop_ref);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> loop {false};
    std::mutex emit_mutex;
    template<class...Ts> void emit(Ts&&...ts){
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(emit_mutex);
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand{
            0,
            ((std::cout << ts << "\n"), 0)...
        });
    }
};


int main(){
    A a;
    a.ChangeLoop();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    a.ChangeLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

When I change loop to false, the thread does not break as I would expect. Alternatively, I tried to have the threaded function look at the member variable without taking any arguments, but had the same issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>

class A
{
public:
    void ChangeLoop(){
        loop = !loop;
            if(loop){
                std::future<void> fi = std::async(std::launch::async, &A::RunLoop, this);
            }
    }
    void RunLoop(){
        while(loop){
            emit(loop);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> loop {false};
    std::mutex emit_mutex;
    template<class...Ts> void emit(Ts&&...ts){
        auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(emit_mutex);
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand{
            0,
            ((std::cout << ts << "\n"), 0)...
        });
    }
};


int main(){
    A a;
    a.ChangeLoop();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    a.ChangeLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I thread my RunLoop function seperately, and have it break when I change member variable loop?

Comment: `std::async` is the wrong choice here. Use `std::thread` in combination with `detach()`. Change `std::future<void> fi = std::async(std::launch::async, &A::RunLoop, this, std::ref(loop));` to `std::thread(&A::RunLoop, this, std::ref(loop)).detach();` or join the new thread somewhere in destructor or whatever. I hope you get the point `std::async` is not the right choice here.

Comment: Thanks @OZ17, this has worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already found the working solution to your problem, I just want to point out why `std::async` is the not the right choice here.

From the online reference on [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound to a reference, **the destructor of the std::future will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes.**

So what you have here is the destructor of `std::future` blocking because the thread with `RunLoop` never completes execution because of its `while` loop.

This is true even when the return value from `std::async` is ignored in `ChangeLoop` and not assigned to a `std::future`.

Some C++ experts say that an `std::future` produced by `std::async` should not block. Here is an [article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3451.pdf) by Herb Sutter where he argues this.

But for now the solution proposed in the comment (of using `std::detach`) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @P.W. After reading through the information you provided and watching Bo Qian's videos on C++ Threading, I understand why I need to use std::thread with detatch in this scenario.